# Is there an one-liner to log the wlan signal quality and the ip-address?

Tags: wireless-networking, bash, python

I would like to log the wireless signal quality and the last number of the IP-address to a text file or an IoT website. Is it possible to extract both in python and/or bash with a simple one-liner?

```
signal-quality: 90
ip-address: 93
```

EDIT: The os is the latest rasbian, if that matters.

Comment: I found out that `ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{split($1,A,"."); print A[4]}'` gives you the last number of the IP address. But ` iwconfig wlan0 | grep 'Link Quality='| awk '{split($1,A,"/"); print A[1]}' ` is not working.

Comment: post the output of `iwconfig wlan0`... it will be easier to grep the part you need. :)

Comment: You can simplify the 1st expression `ifconfig eth | awk '{if ($1=="inet") {split($2,A,"."); print A[4]}}' `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try those 2 lines

```
ifconfig wlan0 | awk '{if ($1=="inet") {split($2,A,"."); print A[4]}}' 

iwconfig wlan0 | awk '{if ($1=="Link"){split($2,A,"/");print A[1]}}'
```

if you do not like Quality=90 as output you can pipe the second command in a `sed`

```
iwconfig wlan0 | awk....  | sed 's/Quality=//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured it out. You can log last IP-number, Link/Signal Quality with these three one-liner

```
ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{split($1,A,"."); print A[4]}' >> ~/logs/iplog
iwconfig wlan0 | grep 'Quality='| cut -d= -f2 | awk '{split($1,A,"/"); print A[1]}' >> ~/logs/linklog
iwconfig wlan0 | grep 'level='| cut -d= -f2 | awk '{split($1,A,"/"); print A[1]}' >> ~/logs/signallog
```